# Create an event after a record has been approved

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process, event

I want to create a event after my record have been approved, I have a checkbox checked when my record is approved so I can create my event, but the record will be locked !!!!

There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was:

> "Apex trigger TRTimeOffAfterUpdate caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: TRTimeOffAfterUpdate: execution of
>   AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only:
>   Trigger.TRTimeOffAfterUpdate: line 4, column 1".

```
trigger TRTimeOffAfterUpdate on Time_Off__c (after update) {

    for (Time_Off__c toEvent : Trigger.new) {
        if(toEvent.Is_approved__c=true){
       // Event event = new Event
       Event ev= new Event 
       (
            OwnerId = toEvent.CreatedById,
            StartDateTime = toEvent.Start_date__c,
            EndDateTime = toEvent.End_date__c,
            Subject = toEvent.Pattern__c,
            Description =  toEvent.Comment__c,
            ShowAs = 'Out of Office'
        );
        insert ev ;             
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a multi-step approval process? Are you indicating via a field update that the record is approved during 'final approval actions'

Comment: Yes I have a multistep approval, with a field update and set the field Is_approved__c checkbox to true once the record is approved! based to this I want to create a event on his calander but only the one who has the right to approve my records (in this situation my manager) can create an event on my calander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I made a small edit to your trigger.
Instead of the single equal sign, you need a double equal sign.
Also, I made it check if the old value was unchecked so you don't keep making records over and over.

```
trigger TRTimeOffAfterUpdate on Time_Off__c (after update) {

for (Time_Off__c toEvent : Trigger.new) {
    if(toEvent.Is_approved__c==true && Trigger.oldMap.get(toEvent.Id).Is_approved__c == false){
   // Event event = new Event
   Event ev= new Event 
   (
        OwnerId = toEvent.CreatedById,
        StartDateTime = toEvent.Start_date__c,
        EndDateTime = toEvent.End_date__c,
        Subject = toEvent.Pattern__c,
        Description =  toEvent.Comment__c,
        ShowAs = 'Out of Office'
    );
    insert ev ;             
}
}
```

Does this work?

Comment: I have here a management rule, is that only the manager who has the right to approve my record, can create an event on my calander after approving my record !!! I think I have to recover the manager ID and assign it to the OwnerId, I'm gonna try it now

Comment: Did my code let you create the event? If so, please mark the answer as the right one so we can close the question.